# CSS: Can't get text in relative-positioned div to center align?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The text in my `TextWrapper` div won't center align. `text-align: center` worked when I didn't use `position: relative` and `: absolute` on them, but they are necessary for my jQuery code. How do I get the text to center align in the div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolute positioning removes the default behavior of block elements to fill the width of their parent element. Either add `width: 100%` or `left: 0; right: 0;` to the absolutely positioned divs.

```js
$(function(){
 $("#TextWrapper div:gt(0)").hide();
 setInterval(function(){
  var current = $('#TextWrapper div:visible');
  var next = current.next().length ? current.next() : $('#TextWrapper div:eq(0)');
  current.fadeOut(500);
  next.fadeIn(500);
 }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.Border {
 border: 1px solid black;
 display: inline-flex;
 height: 110px;
}
#ImgAndText {
 text-align: center;
}
.Img {
 width: 75px;
 height:75px;
}
#TextWrapper {
 font-family: Helvetica;
 font-size: 13px;
 padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
}
#TextWrapper div {
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="Border">

 <div id="ImgAndText"> 
  <img src="#" class="Img">

  <div id="TextWrapper">
   <div>Text</div>
   <div>Other</div>
  </div>
    
 </div> 
     
</div>
```

Comment: So that's what it was, I would've never knew that! Thank you very much!

Comment: @confused5000 you bet :)